# Could not load type 'Telerik.Windows.Documents.Packaging.DeflaterOutputStream'

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, telerik

I've to export some report into pdf. I'm using telerki library **PdfFormatProvider**.

```
PdfFormatProvider p = new PdfFormatProvider();
p.Export(document, stream);
```

But I'm getting exception on `p.Export`.

[image]

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Telerik.Windows.Documents` and has it copied to the same directory as your executable?

Comment: yes it is in same directory.

Comment: What about version ? Is it the same as mentioned in the code or changed ?

Comment: how could we check this? I did not mention any version in code.

Comment: Check in the `config` file. And also matching the one shown in the above error and the one stored on the physical location.

Comment: yes versions are same.

Comment: And what does that match the version of `Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Pdf.dll` or whichever assembly holds `PdfFormatProvider`?

Comment: no that does not match. `Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Pdf.dll` version is `2010.3.1110.1040`

Comment: but in exception it does not specify `Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Pdf.dll` rather it says `Telerik.Windows.Documents`

Comment: @CharlesMager that was the issue. difference between versions. thank you for pointing it out. If you answer it down, I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to mismatch version of `Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Pdf.dll` and `Telerik.Windows.Documents`.